# Check for scrollTo to finish

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an element that is scrollable. I also have a function that scrolls to a specific position. I would like to call a function when the scrollTo is finished.

[Plunkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ejDdIjC0DMjxcYXM3Xlx?p=preview)

```
var x = document.querySelector('.container');
$scope.scrollTo = function() {
  x.scrollTo({
    top: 300 ,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
};

 // do something when scrollTo is finished
```

Comment: The default `scrollTo` do not support the `callback` but you can either write your own implementation or you can use this custom js [scrollTo](https://gist.github.com/james2doyle/5694700)

Comment: It looks like there's no specification for the scroll duration, callbacks or promises on this functionality. You'll have to either use a custom scrolling mechanism, or listen for scroll events and calculate yourself whether the view is in the right position.

Comment: My solution now is using a setInterval to check 2 element positions. Once they are equal the scrollTo animation is complete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By checking the position of the element I am scrolling to and comparing that to the current scroll position of the container you can see when the scrolling action is finished.

```
function isScrollToFinished() {
        const checkIfScrollToIsFinished = setInterval(() => {
            if (positionOfItem === scrollContainer.scrollTop) {
                // do something
                clearInterval(checkIfScrollToIsFinished);
            }
        }, 25);
}
```

The interval checks if the position of the scroll container is equal to the position of the element I'm scrolling to. Then do a action and clear the interval.

Comment: I upvoted this answer yesterday, but after a little bit of time I realized that it's possible that this will never finish, if you try to scroll to a position that's impossible to scroll to, e.g. if the intended scroll position is past the end of the page. Keep that in mind if you want to use this solution!

Answer (score 6):

I suggest checking that the scroll movement is gone.

Less parameter, no risk, and works for extremes positions.

```js
let position = null
const checkIfScrollIsStatic = setInterval(() => {
  if (position === window.scrollY) {
    clearInterval(checkIfScrollIsStatic)
    // do something
  }
  position = window.scrollY
}, 50)
```

Answer (score 2):

I modified [@DoiDor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55824448/2577276) to ensure that the position is rounded and include a timeout fallback just in case. Otherwise the position may never be reached exactly, and the promise would never resolve.

```js
async function scrollToPosition(container, position) {
  position = Math.round(position);

  if (container.scrollTop === position) {
    return;
  }

  let resolveFn;
  let scrollListener;
  let timeoutId;

  const promise = new Promise(resolve => {
    resolveFn = resolve;
  });

  const finished = () => {
    container.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollListener);
    resolveFn();
  };

  scrollListener = () => {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);

    // scroll is finished when either the position has been reached, or 100ms have elapsed since the last scroll event
    if (container.scrollTop === position) {
      finished();
    } else {
      timeoutId = setTimeout(finished, 100);
    }
  };

  container.addEventListener('scroll', scrollListener);

  container.scrollTo({
    top: position,
    behavior: 'smooth',
  });

  return promise;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a solution similar to this:

```
function scrollElementTo(el, position) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const scrollListener = (evt) => {
      if (typeof evt === 'undefined') {
        return;
      }

      const target = evt.currentTarget;

      if (target.scrollTop === position) {
        target.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollListener);
        resolve();
      }
    };

    el.addEventListener('scroll', scrollListener);

    // scroll to desired position (NB: this implementation works for
    // vertical scroll, but can easily be adjusted to horizontal 
    // scroll as well)
    el.scrollTo(0, position);
  });
}

const scrollContainer = document.querySelector('#theScrollContainer');

// desired y coords for scroll
const yDesiredScroll = 234;

scrollElementTo(scrollContainer, yDesiredScroll).then(() => {
    // do something here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is good to take at account situation when:

- someone tries to interact with web browser while scrolling
- web browser has set zoom and floating-o=point numbers are returned by DOM API.

Source: https://dirask.com/posts/JavaScript-check-for-scrollTo-method-got-finished-DnvmED

```
function SmoothScroller(element, interval = 100, chances = 3, tolerance = 1.0) {
    let id = null;
    this.scroll = (x, y, callback) => {
        if (id) {
            clearTimeout(id);
            id = null;
        }
        const options = {
            left: x,
            top: y,
            behavior: 'smooth'
        };
        element.scrollTo(options);
        if (callback) {
            let state = +Infinity;
            const action = () => {
                const elementX = element.scrollLeft;
                const elementY = element.scrollTop;
                const dx = x - elementX;
                const dy = y - elementY;
                const square = dx * dx + dy * dy;
                if (square < tolerance) {
                    callback('done');
                } else {
                    const dx = x - elementX;
                    const dy = y - elementY;
                    const space = dx * dx + dy * dy;
                    if (square === state) {
                        if (chances > 0) {
                            state = space;
                            chances -= 1;
                            id = setTimeout(action, interval);
                        } else {
                            callback('canceled');
                        }
                    } else {
                        state = space;
                        id = setTimeout(action, interval);
                    }
                }
            };
            id = setTimeout(action, interval);
        }
    };
    this.stop = () => {
        if (id) {
            clearTimeout(id);
            id = null;
        }
    };
}


// Usage example:

const element = ...  // e.g. document.querySelector('#element');
const scroller = new SmoothScroller(element);

scroller.scroll(50, 100, (status) => console.log(`status: ${status}`));  // scrolls into (x, y) = (50, 100) position
```